# How to append a new column to an Excel file without changing the existing data on the file using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

After installing pandas and the necessary libraries and reading from an Excel file, I want to add a new column, however when I write back  on the file it deletes the information that already was on the file and just gives the new column.

This is the code I use:

```
pf=pd.DataFrame({'ID': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]})
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(pathdata, engine='xlsxwriter')
pf.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Are you asking how to append data to the existing Excel file?

Comment: yes, so my other data still remains on the file

Comment: what is `pathdata` here?

Answer (score 0):

You are initially pulling the data from excel as **data** and then your are creating a new dataframe, **df**. You then write this new dataframe to excel ( **df**.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1' ). This new dataframe has nothing to do with the data you initially pulled. This should fix your issue:

```
import pandas as pd
pathdata= r'C:\Users\......\........\project.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(pathdata)

data['ID'] = [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]

writer=pd.ExcelWriter(pathdata, engine='xlsxwriter' )
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

If you wanted to fix this issue by creating a new dataframe for the column you want to add you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
pathdata= r'C:\Users\......\........\project.xlsx'
data = pd.read_excel(pathdata)

df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]})
x = [data, df]
data = pd.concat(x, axis = 1)

writer=pd.ExcelWriter(pathdata, engine='xlsxwriter' )
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're not actually reading the data from the Excel file. Without knowing what the actual data looks like, this could be the workflow you want:

```
df = pd.read_excel(pathdata)
df['ID'] = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
df.to_excel(newpathdata)
```

Comment: the reading was done before i wanted to writ back on the file


'

Comment: Can you provide a more complete example?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
pathdata= r'C:\Users\......\........\project.xlsx'
data= pd.read_excel(pathdata)
```

now I want to add this list as an additional column, for example this list ID=[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID':[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]})
writer=pd.ExcelWriter(pathdata, engine='xlsxwriter' )
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

this just gives me the file with just the new column I want the previous info to remain

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the simple code to add new column named "total" in my existing excel file(exceldata.xlsx)**

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook
df = pd.read_excel("exceldata.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
df["total"] = df["Jan"] + df["Feb"] + df["Mar"]
print(df.head())

writer=pd.ExcelWriter("exceldata.xlsx", engine='xlsxwriter' )
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Here is the resultant excel file with **total** named column in it..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xl3K.png)